# How do I look to see if a certain effect is changing over time?

Tags: regression, time-series, interaction, panel-data

My data are a little weird, so I'm going explain them with an example that is analogous to my data.

**RQ:** I want to know if sugary drinks are becoming more popular.

**Data:** I have a list of the 20 most popular drinks every year over the past twenty years, as well as their sugar content.

**Analysis:** I have two ideas on how to analyze the data. I'm curious if they make sense, and if you'd suggest anything else. In each analysis, the data look like this:

| Drink | Rank | Year | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coke | 1 | 2000 | 20 |
| Coke | 3 | 2001 | 20 |
| Milk | 5 | 2000 | 0 |

**1:** Run a regression predicting sugar content using year as a predictor.

**2:** Run a regression predicting a drink's rank each year, using sugar content, year, and their interaction as predictors.

Edit: It looks like this could be a good instance for a time varying coefficient model, with Sugar Varying by Year, Predicting Rank. My understanding is that this would be the same as option 2 but allow for non-linear changes in the effect of sugar over time?

Comment: I can think of different conflicting interpretations of RQ, so it would be nice to get a clearer statement of it.  For instance, if every *type* of sugary drink is being consumed less and less over time but *more types* are being consumed, so that the total quantity of sugary drinks is increasing, would that mean sugary drinks are become more popular, less, or neither? What if the number of consumers were growing faster than the consumption--would that be more or less popular?

Comment: @whuber Oh good point. Am I understanding you correctly that you're saying: there could be more high sugar drinks in the top 20 over time, without the relationship between sugar and rank becoming more positive over time? I hadn't considered that. Do you have a way to deal with that in mind?

Comment: I'm really looking for a clear definition from you concerning what you mean by "more popular." I don't think there's one answer, so it depends on your intention.

Comment: I guess it could be operationalized in two ways. Popularity could simply be presence on the top 20 list. It could also be a higher rank on the list.